# Confusion about MongoDB about how it works

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have installed mongoDB community version I don't know if mongo Daemon also comes with that. I was following [Documentation for ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) as I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

when I run `mongod` it gives this error

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-03-27T20:45:27.371+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-03-27T20:45:27.371+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-03-27T20:45:27.371+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":8754,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"vaibhav"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-03-27T20:45:27.371+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.4","gitVersion":"8db30a63db1a9d84bdcad0c83369623f708e0397","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-03-27T20:45:27.371+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-03-27T20:45:27.371+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-03-27T20:45:27.372+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-03-27T20:45:27.372+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":919}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-03-27T20:45:27.372+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

basically I want to connect node with mongoDB locally. I came across this [Document](https://zellwk.com/blog/local-mongodb/) so I did the same thing that it said. Upon running  `node app.js` I got

(node:14039) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
Connected MongoDB: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
Database: myname

I don't understand if it is connected to the node or not and what is the deprecation message and how to fix it? why doesn't mongod command work mbut whereas `mongo` is working and I can add databases through it? what's the difference between doing that using `mongo` and `mongod`? kindly suggest me document regarding this if there is any.

Comment: The ubuntu documentation you referenced doesn't include a step where you launch mongod directly. Read carefully and do exactly what it says.

Answer (score 2):

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/reference/unified-topology/

> NOTE: In upcoming minor versions useUnifiedTopology will default to true, and in the next major version of the driver this topology will outright replace the legacy topologies.

change from

```
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }
```

to

```
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
```